# Mutually exclusive and independent probability

Tags: probability

Ok, here is a GRE question I cannot seem to solve. My coworker and I keep getting a negative number.

> Of three possible events, event A is independent of the other two, and events B and C are mutually exclusive. The probabilities that the individual events A, B, and C will occur are 0.5, 0.3, and 0.2, respectively. What is the probability that both event A and event C will occur?

[Source: ManhattanGREPrep](https://www.manhattanprep.com/gre/ChallengeProblems/)

Can you please help? Thank you.

**Edit:** Thanks for your answers. The original wording was the following:

> Of three possible events, **events A and B are independent,** and events B and C are mutually exclusive.  The probabilities that the individual events A, B, and C will occur are 0.5, 0.3, and 0.2, respectively.  What is the probability that both event A and event C will occur?

I believe they had realized the original question had a problem and fixed it. I was not aware of it when I posted this question.

Comment: 17 minutes. $ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independence means that 
$$P(A|C)=\frac{P(A\cap C)}{P(C)}=P(A)$$
$$\implies P(A\cap C)=P(A)P(C)$$

I.e, the probability of $A$ occurring wasn't affected by the prior occurrence of $C$. So the probability that $A$ and $C$ will occur (which is $P(A\cap C)$) is $$P(A)P(C)=0.2\cdot 0.5=0.1$$

Comment: http://www.manhattanprep.com/gre/ChallengeProblems/LastWeek/ 
actually, the answer is claimed to be 0.07

Comment: @xorxorxor The answer they give is incorrect. Let $A$ be a coin coming up heads, $B$ be a random number from $1$ to $10$ being in the range $1,2,3$, and $C$ be that same number being $4,5$. Then $P(A\cap C)=1/2\cdot2/10=1/10$. They said it in the question: $B$ is *not* an independent choice, so including it *again* in your answer when you've already indicated that $C$ happens (and so $B$ not happening is redundant) is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

A is indipendent of C, thus the probability of 'A and C' should simply be the product of the probabilities, i.e. 0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Since $B$ and $C$ are exclusive, $B$ can not occur if $A$ and $C$ did. But this is irrelevant, since by independence 
$$
   \mathbb{P}\left(A \land C\right) \stackrel{\text{independence}}{=} \mathbb{P}(A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(C) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{10}
$$

Answer (score 0):

P(AUC)=P(A)+P(C)-P(A∩C)  Now A and C are independent, so P(A∩C)=P(A) P(C)
Therefore the P(AUC) is 0.5 + 0.2 -(0.5) (0.2)=0.5+0.2-0.1=0.6. Now P(A∩C)=P(A) P(C)=0.1.  The problem can only be answered if A and C are independent. The original wording does not provide enough information to solve.